# SQL group by cases statement to crash

Tags: sql, db2

I have a sql query that works great, until I try to implement a group by clause. Currently it is getting all of the rows I am asking for but they need to be grouped other wise I have way too many rows. But once I add a group by, even if its just to group by one column the sql crashes entirely. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The current error message with the SQL as is:

Error Executing Database Query.

[Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB2 UDB]SQL0122 - Column QDSHDT or expression in SELECT list not valid.

And like I had mentioned without the group by clause this error completely goes away and the query runs fine.

```
SELECT  Distinct 'SJ' as JOURNAL, 
        BLNDTA.bln525l1.bclnt,
        (substr(digits(dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHDT),1,2) || substr(digits(dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHDT),3,2)) as YEAR,
        substr(digits(dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHDT),5,2) as shpmm,
        CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN QDAMTBL ELSE 0.0 END as qdamtbl,
        CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN dtalib.odmastl1.QDAWP + dtalib.odmastl1.QDPFEE + dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHIP3 ELSE 0.0 END) + qdadjamt ELSE 0.0 END as NETSALE,
        CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN dtalib.odmastl1.QDCOPAY+dtalib.odmastl1.QDCPAY2 + dtalib.odmastl1.QDDEDCT ELSE 0.0 END as PATRESP,
        CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN dtalib.odmastl1.QDAWP + dtalib.odmastl1.QDPFEE + dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHIP3 ELSE 0.0 END) + qdadjamt ELSE 0.0 END) + QDSLTAX - (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN dtalib.odmastl1.QDCOPAY+dtalib.odmastl1.QDCPAY2 + dtalib.odmastl1.QDDEDCT ELSE 0.0 END) ELSE 0.0 END as prxtot,
        CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN qdamtpd ELSE 0.0 END as qdamtpd,
       (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN dtalib.odmastl1.QDAWP + dtalib.odmastl1.QDPFEE + dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHIP3 ELSE 0.0 END) + qdadjamt ELSE 0.0 END)+qdsltax-(CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN dtalib.odmastl1.QDCOPAY+dtalib.odmastl1.QDCPAY2 + dtalib.odmastl1.QDDEDCT ELSE 0.0 END)-qdamtpd as CLTBALDUE,
        CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN qdcost ELSE 0.0 END as qdcost,
        CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN dtalib.odmastl1.QDAWP + dtalib.odmastl1.QDPFEE + dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHIP3 ELSE 0.0 END) + qdadjamt - qdcost ELSE 0.0 END as gp,
        CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch=bln525l1.bbatch THEN 1 ELSE 0.0 END as OrderCnt,
        CASE WHEN bln525l1.brjrsn <> '   ' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END as DenialCnt, 
        CASE WHEN bln525l1.brjrsn <> '   ' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END as Reshipcnt,
        CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch and (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN dtalib.odmastl1.QDAWP + dtalib.odmastl1.QDPFEE + dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHIP3 ELSE 0.0 END) + qdadjamt ELSE 0.0 END) + QDSLTAX - (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN dtalib.odmastl1.QDCOPAY+dtalib.odmastl1.QDCPAY2 + dtalib.odmastl1.QDDEDCT ELSE 0.0 END) ELSE 0.0 END) <> 0 THEN 1.0 
             WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch and (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN dtalib.odmastl1.QDAWP + dtalib.odmastl1.QDPFEE + dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHIP3 ELSE 0.0 END) + qdadjamt ELSE 0.0 END) + QDSLTAX - (CASE WHEN dtalib.odmastl1.qdbatch = bln525l1.bbatch THEN dtalib.odmastl1.QDCOPAY+dtalib.odmastl1.QDCPAY2 + dtalib.odmastl1.QDDEDCT ELSE 0.0 END) ELSE 0.0 END) = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE NULL END as Shortpd 



FROM        dtalib.odmastl1



LEFT JOIN DTALIB.INV105L1 on (

        dtalib.odmastl1.qdndc5=DTALIB.INV105L1.indc5 
        and dtalib.odmastl1.qdndc4=DTALIB.INV105L1.indc4
        and dtalib.odmastl1.qdndc2=DTALIB.INV105L1.indc2
        and dtalib.odmastl1.qdgener=DTALIB.INV105L1.igener )

LEFT JOIN blndta.gpi205l1 on (

        DTALIB.INV105L1.igpi=gpi205l1.ggpi )

LEFT JOIN blndta.bln525l1 on (

        dtalib.odmastl1.qdordno=bln525l1.brxnum )    

LEFT JOIN dtalib.odmast4l1 on (

        dtalib.odmastl1.qdcocd=dtalib.odmast4l1.q4cocd 
        and dtalib.odmastl1.qdbrcd=dtalib.odmast4l1.q4brcd 
        and dtalib.odmastl1.qddvcd=dtalib.odmast4l1.q4dvcd
        and dtalib.odmastl1.qdtrans=dtalib.odmast4l1.q4trans
        and dtalib.odmastl1.qdline=dtalib.odmast4l1.q4line
        and dtalib.odmastl1.qdprcgrp=dtalib.odmast4l1.q4group
        and dtalib.odmastl1.qdprcclnt=dtalib.odmast4l1.q4clnt 
        and dtalib.odmastl1.qdfill##=dtalib.odmast4l1.Q4FILL## )            

LEFT JOIN dtalib.ohmast on (

        dtalib.odmastl1.qdcocd=dtalib.ohmast.qhcocd 
        and dtalib.odmastl1.qdbrcd=dtalib.ohmast.qhbrcd 
        and dtalib.odmastl1.qddvcd=dtalib.ohmast.qhdvcd 
        and dtalib.odmastl1.qdtrans=dtalib.ohmast.qhtrans ) 


LEFT JOIN blndta.cst115l1 on (

        dtalib.ohmast.qhacct=cst115l1.acct 
        and dtalib.ohmast.qhadnum=cst115l1.adnum )

WHERE       1=1 

        AND dtalib.odmastl1.QDSTATS IN('R3','70') 
        AND SUBSTR(DTALIB.INV105L1.igpi,1,4) NOT IN('9991') 
        AND QDMEDCD NOT IN('CASH','EDUCA','SRVC') 
        AND dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHDT BETWEEN '20170101' and '20991231' 
        AND dtalib.odmastl1.QDRSDT=0

GROUP BY BLNDTA.bln525l1.bclnt, (substr(digits(dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHDT),1,2) || substr(digits(dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHDT),3,2)), substr(digits(dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHDT),5,2)
```

Comment: SQL doesn't "crash".  It may return an error, and if you want people to be able to help you should probably report what error you're seeing (error code and exact error message, ideally)

Comment: ` (substr(digits(dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHDT),1,2) || substr(digits(dtalib.odmastl1.QDSHDT),3,2))` wHY YOU PUT or Condition in group by?

Comment: @SagarGangwal - that's a concatenation operator. SQL isn't C. (Or C++. Or C#. Or Java. Or JavaScript. Or...)\

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Not in SQL Server or MySQL it's not. Which RDBMS are you actually using, Jon J?

Comment: Please correct your tags, based on the erro message is neither `mysql` nor `sql-server` but `DB2`

Comment: Added the error message, unfortunately it does not give much to go off of because when the group by is removed it (and nothing else is changed) the query runs fine

Comment: Changed tags, sorry about that

Comment: Of course, when you GROUP BY all non-aggregated columns in SELECT must be added to GROUP BY.

Comment: Group by with distinct doesn't make sense.

Comment: And this is not a crash (of the DBMS) it's a simple syntax error.

Comment: @P.Salmon - I assume you mean you don't know a reason to use them together.  (I mention this because to say it "doesn't make sense" could also mean that somehow it's not a well-defined behavior in SQL, which is incorrect.)  While there are few uses for it and it probably isn't needed here, it can, in fact, make sense

Comment: @dnoeth thank you, that's what I was missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all your simple select columns in the group by? I doesn't look it.

Comment: That seemed to be the issue, I think I'm just misunderstanding how the group by works, I want the sql to group the rows when the first 4 columns match and add up the rest of the columns

Comment: The thing is that once some columns are grouped (crushed together), there is no way not to group them for the other columns.

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking, when I tried to group by only the first four columns. I was expecting it to give me rows that where the first 4 columns matched the rest of the columns were going to be crunched together, but it still seems to keep them separate as their own rows

Comment: Please explain why this doesn't answer the question so I'll know for next time. The OP didn't know that all columns need to be in the GROUP BY.

Comment: I agree, both @dnoeth and isaace gave me the information needed to fix this problem